# Does Haskell's `Data.Vector.Mutable.unsafeNew` zero the memory?

Tags: haskell, vector

The [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Generic-Mutable.html) says that `new` "creates a mutable vector of the given length" and `unsafeNew` "creates a mutable vector of the given length. The length is not checked."

However [this resolved github issue](https://github.com/haskell/vector/issues/30) indicates that `unsafeNew` does not zero the memory while `new` does.

Which one is it?

Comment: are you asking about length checking or initialization?

Comment: @jberryman I am asking whether "unsafeNew" means "this function does not check bounds" or "this function does not zero memory"

Comment: Note that the behaviors of `new` and `unsafeNew` changed in vector 0.11. Looks like the documentation wasn't updated to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not in general. If you click through the source this is pretty clear:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/src/Data-Vector-Generic-Mutable.html#new

`new` is `unsafeNew` with the addition of `basicInitialize`.

Comment: i'm trying to figure out the difference between ```UNSAFE_CHECK(checkLength) ``` and ```BOUNDS_CHECK(checkLength)```.